# How to override Django apps.py and its AppConfig for third-party apps which is not there?

Tags: python, django

Since Django 1.7 the `AppConfig` feature has been added suggesting that post_migrate signals should be put in the `ready()` part of its customized implementation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/signals/#post-migrate

The basic way to implement `AppConfig` described by the docs is to point to it in the `__init__.py` file using `default_app_config` setting. The docs would also suggest a way to override an existing `AppConfig` for any app:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/applications/#for-application-users

I have researched a bit and found out that django actually creates `AppConfig` instance for every app in `INSTALLED_APPS` even if its custom implementation is not implemented it would bootstrap the default for you.

My question is how one should provide a customized app configuration with `post_migrate` signal for an app that doesn't implement `AppConfig` (the easiest example would be a third party package without apps.py)?

I know that even for this app the django would go and create a default version of `AppConfig` but where and how should i tell it NOT to do so and use my custom `AppConfig` instead with overrided `ready()` method implementation to add `post_migrate`?

Answer (score 7):

Let us suppose for a moment that you wished to create a custom AppConfig for django crispy_forms (which you have installed into your virtualenv).

Step 1: Create a folder named crispy_forms in your project.
Step 2: Create an `__init__.py` in that folder and paste the following

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

default_app_config = 'crispy_forms.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

step 3: Create an apps.py in crispy_forms folder and paste

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):

    verbose_name = 'customized crispy_forms'
    name = "crispy_forms"

    def __init__(self, app_name, app_module):
        AppConfig.__init__(self,app_name, app_module)
        print 'My app config', app_name, app_module
```

If django doesn't reload classes, restart the development server and then you will see something like:

```
My app config crispy_forms <module 'crispy_forms' from '/home/xxx/project/crispy_forms/__init__.pyc'>
```

Comment: Great suggestion! Thanks for that! But in this case i start getting the errors originating from some other parts of my app. The error context is basically like the following: `from crispy_forms.models import SomeModel
ImportError: No module named 'crispy_forms.models'`

Comment: Good observation! I didn't actually try an import from the crispy_forms app before posting this. Will take a look ASAP.

Comment: It seems that if we keep our `name = "crispy_forms"` Django would consider that this new custom app is a crispy_forms rewrite and then when we try to import anything from the initial `crispy_forms` plugin it would try to import it from our app. The `crispy_forms` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` would start pointing to our app with customized `AppConfing` as soon as we use the same name for it.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was quite the same, and answer here helped me  to find a solution. I use in my Django app a dependency to "django-constance" to manage some application parameter inside Admin site.
But I wanted to be sure that some parameters are setup in constance as soon as you use my webapp application.

Unfortunatly, solution provided by @canufeel didn't worked, I could use constance subpackages in my app, 'import errors'.

Here is how I did it :

I created under my app a subpackage named 'myApp/constance', where I defined the same as mentioned by @canufeel. 
But the change was mainly that I don't import anymore 'constance' package in INSTALLED_APPS, but 'myapp.constance' where I could override the settings like this :

```
MYAPP_CONSTANCE_CONFIG_VAR = {
'ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS': (7, 'Number of days before activation is kept available'),
'BOOTSTRAP_THEME': ('slate', 'Bootstrap theme for front end', 'select_theme'),
...
}
```

Then override :

```
BASE_CONSTANCE_CONFIG = getattr(settings, 'CONSTANCE_CONFIG', {})
BASE_CONSTANCE_CONFIG.update(MYAPP_CONSTANCE_CONFIG_VAR)

settings.CONSTANCE_CONFIG = BASE_CONSTANCE_CONFIG_VAR
settings.CONSTANCE_ADDITIONAL_FIELDS = BASE_CONSTANCE_ADDITIONAL_FIELDS
settings.CONSTANCE_CONFIG_FIELDSETS = WAVES_CONSTANCE_CONFIG_FIELDSETS
```

that does the trick, still I think this is not a 'state of the art' solution :-)

Comment: Remark : this solution may not work if multiple apps require to update constance configuration....

Comment: Just pointed out in my project, in fact just need to add a file called by example "myapp_constance.py" in my apps, and include it in my __init__.py... job done, quite easy in fact :-)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the other suggestions and they didn't work for me. But the official documentation did. The solution is so simple: [For application users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#for-application-authors)

To quote the Manual:

> If you’re using “Rock ’n’ roll” in a project called anthology, but you
>   want it to show up as “Jazz Manouche” instead, you can provide your
>   own configuration:

```
# anthology/apps.py

from rock_n_roll.apps import RockNRollConfig

class JazzManoucheConfig(RockNRollConfig):
    verbose_name = "Jazz Manouche"

# anthology/settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'anthology.apps.JazzManoucheConfig',
    # ...
]
```