# Django third party app name conflicts

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, pinax

I have been trying to get two third party apps to play nice together, and it just hasn't been working for me, due to their names.

The two apps I am trying to get to work are `django-user-accounts` and `django-allauth`.  The problem is, both apps are using the same namespace "account", and I don't understand the way I'm supposed to fix them.

I did find some things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865765/how-to-override-django-apps-py-and-its-appconfig-for-third-party-apps-which-is-n), which seem to be the way to go about fixing it, but when I try to implement it, I have two problems.

1. It doesn't seem to do anything at all for django-user-accounts.
2. With django-allauth, there are many different apps underneath the `allauth` package, and to get the account app folder for it, I have to also create the `allauth` folder first, which makes those other apps inaccessible.

Here's what I have so far.

Under my project folder I created this structure:

```
allauth
├── account
│   ├── apps.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

In `allauth.account.__init__`, I have:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

default_app_config = 'allauth.account.apps.CustomAccountAppConfig'
```

In `allauth.account.apps` I have:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class CustomAccountAppConfig(AppConfig):

    verbose_name = 'custom account'
    name = "allauth.account"
    label = "custom_account"

    def __init__(self, app_name, app_module):
        AppConfig.__init__(self,app_name, app_module)
```

This appears to resolve the conflict with the name, but I then get `ImportError: No module named 'allauth.socialaccount'`, because it has overridden the allauth package.

How can I solve this naming conflict and keep all other subpackages and applications working?

Comment: Why don't you try creating the `socialaccount` directory too just like you did for `account` app

Comment: The problem I have is that I can add all the packages, but adding packages doesn't import the individual files.  For instance, the `allauth.urls` file is not available.  At this rate, I might as well just copy the entire app to my project.

Comment: I'm curious why you are trying to use both packages?  You should just need one or the other.

Comment: If you mean the python sdk, and the rest API, they are actually the same thing.  The sdk communicates over the API.

Comment: Patrick, I just realized what you meant.  Sorry.  I was going to use pinax-stripe, and they make it easy to setup using pinax, which comes with django-user-accounts.  I also need to validate some things using oauth, which is provided by allauth.  I am thinking I'm going to just have to bite the bullet and forego the simplicity of using pinax.

Comment: pinax-stripe doesn't require django-user-account.  but you could also use python-social-auth if you all you need form allauth are social/oauth connections.  that said, if it's just a simple oauth connection, you don't really need a package for that.

Comment: hi, I'm not sure  but could you try in the main urls.py file when using include method, give each one a new namespace and check that.

Comment: If I remember correctly, those packages expect their namespaces to be used, so remapping URLs would still have the same problem.  Having said that, I believe I ended up using Patrick Altman's suggestion.  It's been 3 years though, so I don't remember for sure.

Comment: Maybe you created name space for `alluth.account` but not for `allauth.socialaccount`. Create a separate `app.config` for the previous.

Comment: When you're having this kind of troubles I agree with the solution taken so far: you're definitely relying on too many third-party packages.

This being said, by a quick look to the `django-user-account` source code I think that the reason why the mentioned solution doesn't work is simply that they never defined an app. configuration. So, instead of trying to override theirs, why don't you just try to define it in your code?

Comment: I would stick to django-allauth and not use anything else. It has a lot of customization capabilities.

Comment: There have been many changes since this was written almost 6 years ago.  I don't even remember what I ended up doing back then.  Two of the packages I was dealing with in this question are no longer being maintained actively, as far as I can tell.  Those being django-user-accounts and pinax-stripe.  Either way, I just use django-allauth, and djstripe these days.

Comment: @PoDuck It looks to me that the actual problem is namespace shadowing. Because your local package is called `allauth`, there was a conflict with third-party one. It could have been solved by renaming package or by following popular convention by moving extension packages to `contrib` package in your project.

Answer (score 1):

### Do this to resolve the 3rd party app name conflicts:

you can follow these steps.

**- Create a Custom AppConfig for "django-allauth"**

You can create a custom AppConfig for the "account" app within the "django-allauth" package to change its name and label. This should help in avoiding the conflict with the "django-user-accounts" package. Here's how you can do it:

In your project structure, create the following files:

```html
your_project/
├── allauth
│   ├── account
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── your_project/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── settings.py
```

and in "allauth/account/apps.py", define a custom AppConfig for the "account" app:

```html
# allauth/account/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class CustomAccountAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'allauth.account'  # Set the full app name
    label = 'custom_account'  # Set a unique label for the app
    verbose_name = 'Custom Account'  # Set a human-readable name

    def ready(self):
        # Import signals and connect them here if needed
        pass
```

**Update "allauth" AppConfig in settings.py:**

In your project's "settings.py" file, make sure to use the custom AppConfig you created for the "account" app within the "allauth" package:

```html
# your_project/settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'allauth.account.apps.CustomAccountAppConfig',  # Use the custom AppConfig
    # ...
]
```

**Verify Subpackages and Applications:**

Ensure that the other subpackages and applications within "django-allauth" are not affected by this change. The custom AppConfig should only affect the "account" app, leaving the rest of the "allauth" functionality intact.

**Import Naming Changes:**

If you were using the "account" namespace in your code to access features from these packages, you'll need to update the imports to reflect the new naming. For example:

```html
# Before
from allauth.account.models import UserProfile

# After
from allauth.account.models import UserProfile
```

**Why this approch:**

This approach should *resolve the naming conflict between "django-user-accounts" and "django-allauth" while keeping the other subpackages and applications within "django-allauth" working as expected.*

Note: Remember to test the changes thoroughly to ensure everything is functioning as intended.

Hope it helps.